# Adobe Omniture - make a test account

Tags: testing, adobe, analytics, sandbox, adobe-analytics

I need to use the [Adobe Oauth2](http://marketing.adobe.com/developer/en_US/documentation/authentication/auth-overview) API to develop the functionality to query our clients Omniture traffic data (after they have given access to it using [3 legged OAuth : WebServer](https://marketing.adobe.com/developer/en_US/documentation/authentication/auth-web-server)).

However for testing I require an Adobe ID and SiteCatalyst account, for which I have to pay. Naturally having no need for an analytics tool myself I have no interest in paying it. Is there no way to get a 'test' account with some data but not tracking any real site? Mentions to Adobe sandbox suggest that might no longer be in use.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you should ask your client to pay? or use their ID?

Comment: Our customers are already full-paying Adobe analytics users, however to build & test the 3 legged OAuth I can't use them (as I expect 404s, issues with tokens, etc.). I would much rather built the functionality on some sandbox like account and only get them involved when I we can actually handle the authorisation process.

Comment: And it isn't just about the client paying, it is that the client then needs to grant admin access to the third party developer in order to setup the integration.